# Potential theory: Fundamental solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, potential-theory, fundamental-solution

After a brief introduction to distribution theory, I have been given the definition of fundamental solution for an operator $\mathcal{L}$ as follows:

> Given a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and a point $y\in\Omega$, it is said that $K(x,y)$ is a fundamental solution of the differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ in $\Omega$ with pole $y$ when
>   $$\mathcal{L}K(\cdot,y)=\delta_y\text{ in }\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$$

we are trying to solve the equation
$$\Delta u(x)=f(x)\text{ for }x\in\Omega$$
and the notes says that the following function should be a solution, here is where I am having troubles to understand
$$u(y)=\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)f(x)dx$$
My problem is that, by defintion, the identity
$$\varphi(y)=\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\Delta\varphi(x)dx$$
only holds for every test functions, so my concrete question are:

1- Aren't we assuming the solution $u$ is a test function? Which would mean that it is $C^\infty$ instead of just $C^2$ as required by the equation.

2- This might be almost the same as the first question but, all we know is $f\in C(\Omega)$, so (I think) it can't be the Laplacian for any test function, and again the previous equation is verfied only by those.

Comment: have you solved your question?

Comment: I wouldn't say I have, although I came to the conclusion that when it says "the following function should be a solution", it means that it follows from intuition, mainly because afterwards they don't mention anything about distribution theory anymore, and they proof that statement properly.

Comment: what do you mean by $\varphi(y)=\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\Delta\varphi(x)dx$? I don't see how this holds even for test functions, since $\Delta = \sum_i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial_{y_i}^2}$  and one doesn't pass the derivatives (with respect to $y$ in an integral with respect to $x$). How do you obtain this relation?

Comment: That's because $K$ is a fundamental solution for $\Delta$.

Since $\mathcal{L}K(\cdot,y)=\delta_y$ they must agree on any test function $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, therefore 
$$\varphi(y)= \langle\delta_y, \varphi\rangle=\langle\Delta K(\cdot,y), \varphi\rangle=\langle K(\cdot, y), \Delta \varphi\rangle$$
and, assuming $K(\cdot, y)\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ (this I omitted in the post, which could have lead to this confusion), that last term equals to $\int_{\Omega}K(x,y)\Delta\varphi(x) dx$.

Also, derivatives have been always with respect $x$ in this post.